# How to pass -FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled to Xamarin iOS App?

Tags: xamarin.ios, firebase-analytics

I'm trying to pass the argument *-FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled* to my Xamarin iOS App but I seem to not have found the correct place in Xamarin Studio to put it. I tried as additional *mtouch* argument like

`--argument=--app-arg=-FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled`

or

`--argument=-FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled`

but neither worked.

I keep seeing this line in the application output:

> Firebase Analytics v.3402000 started
>
> To enable debug logging set the following
>   application argument: -FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled (see
>   goo.gl/Y0Yjwu)

The google short link doesn't link anywhere anymore

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=43899 the fix seems to be to add the following text to "Extra mlaunch Arguments":
--argument=-FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled

Comment: This option is currently only available in the Alpha channel of Xamarin Studio!

Comment: This is correct, however in Xamarin Studio 6.2 (build 1829), if you add this to "Extra mlaunch Arguments" and leave Arguments empty, it will not pass the parameters correctly. Adding "--argument=-FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled" to both fields will fix that.